# OkHttp bad requestBody

Tags: android, utf-8, request, response, okhttp

I am using OkHTTP and I have some problems when I try to make a post request.

Here is my code :

```
client = new OkHttpClient();
formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add(Constant.DIRECTION, Constant.OUT)
                    .add(Constant.LIMIT, Constant.docs_limit)
                    .add(Constant.IMPORTED, Constant.FALSE)
                    .addEncoded("statuses[]", "4")
request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .addHeader(Constant.AUTH_TOKEN, sharedPreferences.getString(Constant.TOKEN, ""))
                        .post(formBody)
                        .build();
```

when I try to send

> "statuses[]", "4"

in the debugger it shows that brackets converted to **"statuses%5B%5D"**.
How to fix that? Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: well im pretty sure the addEncoded method uses some kind of URLEncoder . so perhaps try just using the add method like so 
    .add("statuses[]", "4")

Comment: @Yeti I'm also use .add("statuses[]", "4"), but it doesn't work

Comment: well I have never actually needed to un-encode something like this but perhaps you could "hack it" (not recommended but). by removing it from formbuilder and adding it to the url.        
Request.Builder().url(url+"?statuses[]=4")

Comment: emm shouldnt you use formBody.build() instead of formBody?

Comment: @DEADMC oh sorry here it's like RequestBody formBody

Comment: @DEADMC Could I write RequestBody body = new RequesBody.Builder() ?

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen I mean try to change .post(formBody) to .post(formBody.build())

Comment: @DEADMC ok will try to do it

Comment: @DEADMC still not work :(

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen .addEncoded("statuses[]", "4").build() too? I mean at the end of the builder pattern.