# How to put Array of integer into postRequest via OkHttp?

Tags: android, django, post, okhttp

I am asking this question again. I haven't any idea how to it.

First of all, in my post request I send array of integers. Yes I know that in Android it must be send like String. But main problem here backend was developed on django, and into method which takes my data like below:

```
statuses = request.POST.getlist('statuses[]')
```

And in Android I trying to this:

```
client = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
    .add(Constant.DIRECTION, direction)
    .add(Constant.IMPORTED, imported)
    .add(Constant.LIMIT, limit)
    .add("statuses[]", Arrays.toString(new 
     int[]{Document_Constants.DocumentStatus.Send.getStatus(),
          Document_Constants.DocumentStatus.Success.getStatus(),
          Document_Constants.DocumentStatus.Canceled.getStatus(),
          Document_Constants.DocumentStatus.Revoked.getStatus()}))
    .build();
    request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .addHeader(Constant.AUTH_TOKEN,         
         sharedPreferences.getString(Constant.TOKEN, ""))
        .post(formBody)
        .build();
```

And into code below I think every android developer know about problems, when trying to put `statuses[]` problems with brackets, which will be changed to something like `%5D` something like this, and I haven't any idea how to fix that.

Comment: What's your output? What's the data representation look like? Post a sample status list

Comment: @FazilZaid
when I send "statuses[]", [4,6]
[json](https://pastebin.com/JmVwmDEb)

Comment: Could you please edit the question by adding the current output and what you want to do with that

Comment: @FazilZaid my problem that when I send post request "statuses[]" it was converted to "statuses%5D" and in backend it' trying to get "statuses[]" and can't find this post. How I can send "statuses[]" in correct form

Comment: Encode it to json then stringify it then send..

Comment: Don't send it as a list

Comment: @FazilZaid okay thank you

Comment: @FazilZaid do you know how to decode URL in above code?

Comment: sorry, man, I am yet to learn android, If there's some issue regarding django, ie, forms, models, views I could help. I am helpless as you are buddy..

Comment: Is this a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977865/okhttp-bad-requestbody)?